# Checking if a file exists based on a wildcard in the file name

Tags: regex, file, perl

I have a set of partial filenames, that I need to check against subsequent data delivery packages.
For example, some of the entries in my "blue print" set are:

<NAME>
FILE_ONE
FILE_TWO
FILE_THREE

The actual delivery will contain following files:

<NAME>_<TIMESTAMP>_<SEQUENCE>.<EXTENSION>
FILE_ONE_20180712104010_001.CSV
FILE_TWO_20180712112510_001.CSV
FILE_THREE_20180712112920_001.CSV

Now I would like to read my blue print list in a loop and check whether all files arrived.
I do a check via the name + I would like to concatenate any 14 digits + I would like to concatenate the sequence number coming as a parameter + I would like to concatenate the extension.

My code looks like this:

```
my $bp="blueprint.txt"; #list of partial file names I would like to look for

open my $handle, '<', $bp;
chomp(my @files = <$handle>);
close $handle;

foreach (@files) {
    if(! -f "$_" + "_/\d{14}/_" + $ARGV[0] + ".CSV")
    {
      print "$_ does not exist\n";
    }
}
```

It throws following errors:

```
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE
```

Please help me with the `if` statement.

Comment: `glob` is an alternative to regex matching that you can use with filenames

Comment: Where's the rest of the error message (in particular, the line number)?

Comment: I don't think that error message was generated by the code you've shown us. There's no match operator (`m/.../`) in that code. The only thing that looks like one (`/\d{14}/`) is actually just a string.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using [`readdir`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) to collect all filenames in the current directory. For example:

```
my $seq_num = $ARGV[0];
my $dir = '.';
my @matches;

opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "Can't opendir $dir: $!";
while (my $name = readdir $dh) {
    for my $bp ( @files ) {
        if ( $name =~ /^\Q$bp\E_\d{14}_\Q$seq_num\E\.CSV/ ) {
            push @matches, $bp;
            last;
        }
    }
}
closedir $dh;
```